# optional name argument in tensor flow API's

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am beginner in tesnor flow. Trying to understand about various API's and features. For most of the API's in tensor flow has name argument like shown below

```
# Create a variable.
w = tf.Variable(0, name="abc">)
```

In most of the programming example "w" is used. I am not getting when name optional argument is used for example how "abc" is used either inside the variable function and how it used in following lines after executing above statement. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Name argument is used in most cases so you can restore your variables from a saved checkpoint. Check this https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model . Furthermore it is helpful for finding your variables or operations that are visualized in the graph through tensorboard.